# Auto indent method chaining in Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, sublimetext, sublimetext3, code-formatting, auto-indent

**As I type** the following javascript code (exact keystrokes):

```
myObject
.doSomething()
.doSomethingElse();
```

I'd expect it to automatically become the following...

```
myObject
    .doSomething()
    .doSomethingElse();
```

... as would any other programmer, right?

How do I enable this, and why isn't it enabled by default?

Comment: I am searching for this feature as well. Have you found anything?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Sublime Code formatter](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter) with support JavaScript/JSON Beautifier, this [link](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter#usage) will show you how to usage this plugin.

Or another way is to insert your code inside `Key Bindings - User` file:

```
{"keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

Comment: @japrescott I don't really use sublime text anymore. If this works for you, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Built in `reindent` won't format code as expected. Contrary it will become 'as typed', because it's the way `st3` thinks it should be.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because sublime's `smart_indent` is not smart enough.

You can fix indentation post factum using code formatter plugin like [JsFomat](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JsFormat).

Or preventively indent first chained method call. Following lines will have same level of indentation.
This solution can be slightly improved by creating new key binding:

```
    {
        "keys": ["alt+enter"],
        "command": "insert",
        "args": {"characters": "\n\t"}
    }
```

Press `alt+enter` instead of `enter, tab` for newline to have extra indentation.